# Replacing __str__ in new-style class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm converting old Python code and replaced some classes with new style classes. The problem is that this broke the behavior of replacing `__str__` and I have no idea why.

```
class OldStyle():
    def __str__(self):
        return 'original'

old = OldStyle()
print old
old.__str__ = lambda: 'modified'
print old


class NewStyle(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'original'

new = NewStyle()
print new
new.__str__ = lambda: 'modified'
print new
```

I expected

```
original
modified
original
modified
```

but I got

```
original
modified
original
original
```

That is, `__str__` was not correctly replaced in the new style. Printing `new.__str__` returns the new lambda correctly, but `str(new)` still doesn't call it. I thought it was some method lookup caching problem, but this happens even if the object was never printed before.

Why does that happen? I have never heard about this behavior difference and it only happens with `__str__`, other methods are replaced fine.

Comment: Replacing the last modification with `NewStyle.__str__ = lambda self: 'modified'` works as expected. I think the method resolution order is different between old- and new-style classes.

Comment: Interesting. The problem is that I need to replace `__str__` in only that single instance. I think I can implement it another way, but I got curious.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have code replacing `__str__` on instances in the first place? Sounds... ugly.

Comment: @BoppreH: consider subclassing then, and have the subclass implement to-string however you like.

Comment: @Wooble It's a tree, I use `str(child)` to print children and I want a specific child to be printed with surrounding HTML tags for highlighting. I agree, it's ugly, and it has already been reworked because of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented in the python Data model under [special method names](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).  Specifically:

> For instance, if a class defines a method named `__getitem__`, and x is an instance of this class, then `x[i]` is roughly equivalent to `x.__getitem__(i)` for old-style classes and `type(x).__getitem__(x, i)` for new-style classes.

I believe that this allows new-style classes to be a little more efficient in terms of these operations because with the old style classes, python was forced to look up the attribute and then call the attribute, with new-style classes, python can just reference it as part of a C struct somewhere effectively pushing the lookups and calls into native C code.  For example:

```
class Foo:
    def __add__(self,other):
        return 4 + other

class Bar(object):
    def __add__(self,other):
        return 4 + other

import timeit
print timeit.timeit('f + 5','from __main__ import Foo; f = Foo()')
print timeit.timeit('b + 5','from __main__ import Bar; b = Bar()')
```

For me (python2.7.3, OS-X 10.5.8), the new-style class is almost 4 times faster!

```
2.27801704407
0.602614879608
```

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
NewStyle.__str__ = lambda self: 'modified'
```

It seems like what we're seeing is that the `__str__` method is tied to the class type now, rather than the instance.  I'm not sure why that is.  You can call `new.__str__()` explicitly and get the replaced method, but `str(new)` always calls `NewStyle.__str__(new)`.

Comment: But that changes the behavior of all `NewStyle` instances.

Comment: Of course it does.  Perhaps you should make a derived class and instantiate it for the one instance you want a different to-string behavior on.