# How to replace __str__ for a function

Tags: python, string, function

I want to change the string representation of a python function to be just the function name.

Eg for some function

```
def blah(x):
 ...
```

`str(blah)` currently gives

```
<function blah at 0x10127b578>
```

So I replace `__str__` like this:

```
blah.__str__=lambda: 'blah'
```

but it doesn't get called by `str(blah)`.

Is it possible to change `__str__` for a function?

Comment: use a class instead ...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493025/why-cant-i-replace-the-str-method-of-a-python-object-with-another-function since you're trying to override an instance of the `function` class's `.__str__` argument, the latter which is only designed to be replaced in the class definition.

Comment: just a minor aside,  In general I would avoid this kind of thing as it makes it hard for other people who may have to work on your code.  while its nice and convient, typically explicit is better than implicit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Joran said:

```
class NamedFunction:
    def __init__(self, name, f):
        self.f = f
        self.name = name

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


f = NamedFunction("lambda: 'blah'", lambda: 'blah')
print(f())
print(f)
```

Comment: ahh I was in the process of putting an almost identical answer ... (+1 all the same :P)

Answer (score 10):

Replacing `__str__` like that never actually works on any type of object. The builtin function type isn't special:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
    pass

>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.__str__ = lambda: 'f'
>>> str(f)
'<__main__.Foo object at 0x0000000002D13F28>'
>>> f.__str__()
'f'
```

The `str` builtin doesn't lookup `__str__` via the usual lookup protocol, it skips straight to looking at the class of its argument. So you can't "override" the `__str__` method on an individual object; you have to set it on a class to apply to all objects of that class.<sup>1</sup>

But then again, the builtin function type isn't special. You can make a class that behaves mostly like a function, and use that instead:

```
class Function(object):
    def __init__(self, raw_function):
        self.raw_function = raw_function
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.raw_function(*args, **kwargs)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.raw_function.__name__
```

The `__call__` method means you can call objects of this class exactly as if they were functions. This one just passes whatever arguments it receives straight through to the underlying raw function and returns whatever it returns (or throws whatever exceptions it throws). And since this class takes a single function as an argument, it also fits the pattern for a decorator:

```
@Function
def blah(x):
    return x + 1
```

With that:

```
>>> blah
<__main__.Function object at 0x0000000002D13EB8>
>>> str(blah)
'blah'
>>> blah(33)
34
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The builtin function type *is* special in some regards (I lied), one of which being that you can't assign to its attributes (that's the attributes of the *class* itself, not the attributes of any particular function object). So before you think maybe it would be great if you could monkeypatch the builtin function type so that `str` worked the way you want on *all* functions, that doesn't work. It's probably for the best; modifying things as global and fundamental as the builtin function type would be a great way to invent some really bizarre bugs.

Answer (score 4):

```
class FNMagic:
     def __init__(self,fn,fn_name):
         self.fn = fn 
         self.fn_name = fn_name
     def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
         return self.fn(*args,**kwargs)
     def __str__(self):
         return self.fn_name


def blah(x):
    return x

blah = FNMagic(blah,"blah!")
print blah
```

you could make a simple decorator

```
class NamedFn:
    def __init__(self,name):
       self.fn_name = name
    def __call__(self,fn):
        return FNMagic(fn,self.fn_name)

@NamedFn("some_name!!!")
def blah2(x,y):
     return x*y

print blah2
```

Comment: I'm a little light on experience with decorators, but this seems like a good use for one. Maybe add a little code about it?

Comment: theres a simple decorator ... (of coarse the FnMagic class could have been declared inside the decorator but that would work fine)

Answer (score 3):

As noted already, the answer is no. If you just want to get the name of a function as a string, you can use `blah.__name__`.