# How do you change the way a function is printed?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a Python function that generates a parameterized function like this:

```
def fgen(a):
    def f(x):
        return a * x
    f.__doc__ = """Multiply x by {}""".format(a)
    f.__name__ = 'F{}'.format(a)
    return f
```

If I now use it like this:

```
f2 = fgen(2)
print(f2(2))
help(f2)
print(f2)
```

I get this output:

```
4
Help on function F2 in module __main__:

F2(x)
    Multiply x by 2

<function fgen.<locals>.f at 0x1104a5840>
```

I wondered if it is possible for the last line to be something like:

```
y = 2 * x
```

I thought maybe you could do something like:

```
f.__str__ = lambda object: 'y = {} * x'.format(a)
```

but this does not seem to have any effect on what is printed. Neither does f.**repr**.

I know I can create a class with **str** and **call** methods to achieve this, but I wanted to do it with just functions if possible.

Comment: Important answer in the duplicate: “No, because `repr(f)` is done as `type(f).__repr__(f)` instead.”

Comment: Handy examples of using `class` are provided in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797580/how-to-replace-str-for-a-function