# Write a function to calculate the sum of numbers in python, which is called many times as sum (1) (2) (3)

Tags: python

You need to write a function on python that is called an indefinite number of times, each time it takes a number and returns their sum, for example sum (1) (2) (3) == 6. I found the code for javascript, but I did not find how to redefine it in python __str __ method for the function. How can I override a method or is there another solution?

The code I tried to write:

```py
def sum(n):
    total = n
    def f(k):
        nonlocal total
        total += k
        # f.__str__ = lambda : print(total) # no
        return f
    return f

print(sum(1)(2)(3))
```

This is working javascript code:

```
function sum(a) {

  let currentSum = a;

  function f(b) {
    currentSum += b;
    return f;
  }

  f.toString = function() {
    return currentSum;
  };

  return f;
}

alert( sum(1)(2) ); // 3
alert( sum(5)(-1)(2) ); // 6
alert( sum(6)(-1)(-2)(-3) ); // 0
alert( sum(0)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) ); // 15
```

Comment: Can you use a class? Then you can use its `__call__()` method to allow it to be called as a function, and `__str__` for when the final result is printed.

Comment: I need to use only functions.

Comment: The task is total nonsense, essentially, in both languages.

Comment: You might want to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797580/how-to-replace-str-for-a-function

Comment: Your javascript function doesn't return the sum, just so you know, it returns a function object, not an Number at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
def summ(a):
    current_sum = a

    return lambda x: current_sum + x

print(summ(1)(2))
>>>3
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use a `class` instead of an inner function, and return an object of that class. You would then be able to use the magic `__call__` method again and again, if you make it return the same object.

```
def sum(n):
    class Sum(object): 
        def __init__(self, k):
            self.total = k

        def __call__(self, k):
            self.total += k
            return self

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.total)

        def __repr__(self):
            return str(self)

    return Sum(n)
```

**Output**

```
>>> sum(1)
1
>>> sum(1)(2)
3
>>> sum(1)(2)(3)
6
```

Comment: This doesn't return the sum, btw.

Answer (score 0):

If the function is going to be used as `func(a)(b)(c)(d)(...)` why not just use `func([a,b,c,d,...])` ? In this case:

```
sum([a,b,c,d])
```

Comment: The task requires `func (a) (b) (c) (d) (...)`.

Comment: The whole point of the exercise is to learn about higher-order functions.