# python, why is str(function) ignoring function.__str__()?

Tags: python

I tried to overload the **str** and **repr** methods for a python function, like so:

```
def func():
  pass

func.__str__ = lambda: 'func_str'
func.__repr__ = lambda: 'func_repr'
```

Calling these methods directly produces the exepcted output:

```
print(func.__str__())#output: func_str
print(func.__repr__())#output: func_repr
```

But calling the str() and repr() methods on the func object directly seems to ignore the overloaded methods:

```
print(str(func)) # <function func at 0x0000023C148CC310>
print(repr(func)) # <function func at 0x0000023C148CC310>
```

Question: Why is `str(func)` not the same as `func.__str__()`? If this is not the intended way of giving a function a `str()` and `repr()`, what would be the best approach?

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797580/how-to-replace-str-for-a-function), this has been answered before.

Comment: I don't see the reason for using `__str__` and `__repr__` methods for a function. People generally use them in classes for their objects to display some attribute information about themselves. Example: Imagine a  class `Car` with attribute `model_name` or `registration_no`. You can then use the above methods to display them.

Comment: str(a) calls type(a).__str__(a), therefore str(func) actually is type(func).__str__(func).

Comment: Essentially, setting special methods, i.e. "dunder" methods on instances is usually useless because they are looked up on the type directly as an optimization.  This means you cannot modify dunder methods on a per-instance basis, or (sanely) monkey-patch built-in types