# How to overwrite __repr__ method for an already-instantiated class python

Tags: python, attributes, new-operator, overwrite

I'm working with a 3rd-party library which has a poor **repr** for a class and I would like to overwrite it once an instance of that class has been created.

I saw how to create bound methods in an existing object.

```
class toy():
    pass

inst= toy()

class inhtoy():
    def __new__(cls,obj):
        def __repr__(self):
            return 'Sucessful'
        import types
        obj.__repr__ = types.MethodType(__repr__,obj)
        return obj

t = inhtoy(inst)
```

Indeed, if I call t.**repr**() it works, however it does not overwrite the original **repr**. It appears as `<bound method inhtoy.__new__.<locals>.__repr__ of <__main__.toy object at 0x7f76e0b61f98>>`
a kind of local method.
Calling `repr(t)` still points to the original representation `'<__main__.toy object at 0x7f76e0b61f98>'` but not the overwritten one.

Is there a way to properly do this?
Thanks

Comment: As bad as their `__repr__` may be, replacing it with a substitute of your own is going to be even more confusing.

Comment: while i would also like to know how to do this to a live instance, why not subclass their class and just changing the `__repr__`?

Comment: @Nullman Because subclassing would require the user to inherit it. It would also change class name generating incompatibilities with 3rd-party library. Modifiying the object keeps everything the same.

Answer (score 3):

@Nullman's answer works, because their solution is actually changing the class object `toy`, that `t` is an instance of, not the instance itself, as your approach does.

The special attribute [`__class__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#instance.__class__) references the class object an instance belongs to.

```
print(t.__class__ is toy) # True
```

So, `t.__class__.__repr__ = my_custom_repr` assigns to `__repr__` on the class `toy`, not on the instance `t`.

This becomes visible when comparing the output of `print(t.__repr__)` between your approach and Nullman's. Assuming that a module-level function `__repr__` looks like this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return repr(self.__class__)
```

Your solution shows:

```
<bound method __repr__ of <__main__.toy object at 0x00000000029E5A90>>
```

Note, it says `__main__.toy object`.
 Nullman's solution shows it as:

```
<bound method __repr__ of <class '__main__.toy'>>
```

When you invoke `t.__repr__()` using your approach, you call the method you set on the instance `t`, hence it returns what you made it retun; the string `Success` in your example.
When using [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr), however, the *class* defines the output:

> A class can control what this function returns for its instances by
>   defining a `__repr__()` method.

As Nullman rightfully pointed out, their approach will change the behavior of all existing *and* future objects, instantiated from `toy`.

As for the strange name, that the assigned method shows when using your code:

```
<bound method inhtoy.__new__.<locals>.__repr__ of <__main__.toy object at 0x7f76e0b61f98>>
```

... that's the function object's [qualified name](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-qualified-name) coming from the [`__qualname__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__qualname__) special attribute. It's the function `__repr__` from the local scope of your class `inhtoy`'s method `__new__`.
Speaking of which, passing your instance `inst` through the magic method `__new__` of your `inhtoy` class does not really achieve much. Your code is functionally equivalent to:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "Success"

inst.__repr__ = types.MethodType(__repr__, obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

after some looking around i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10493071/7540911) answer. the way to do it is on a live instance is:

```
t.__class__.__repr__ = my_custom_repr
```

please note that **this changes all class instances** and not just this instance

Comment: Well, for my purpose it will work. Do you have any insight about why it works that way?

Comment: unfortunately not, but if you figure it out i would be happy if you let me know

Comment: @Nullman I added an answer in an attempt to explain why your solutions works and the OP's doesnt; in case you are still interested ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use inheritance to create a new class derived from the class of interest, and then overriding the **repr** method

```
class inhtoy(toy):

    def __init__(self):
        toy.__init__(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        # Your repr method
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a subclass and assign it to the instance, which you get from the library like this:

```
class Toy():
    pass
inst = Toy()  # from 3rd party library

class Toy_MyRepr(Toy):
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<my repr of Toy instance >'

inst.__class__ = Toy_MyRepr
```